# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, occur during merging two project in to single project

Tags: android, android-module

I need to merge to android project in to single project. For doing this I changed one project from application module to library module and import it as a module in second project and its imported successfully, but when i run the project they show error `Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs`

Below is my app module menifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.project.core">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo_fav"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_logo_fav"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:label,android:name">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/sample_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.videodetails.VideoDetailsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.signup.SignUpActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.home.HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.channellist.ChannelListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.setting.SettingActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.seeallvideos.SeeAllVideosActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.editprofile.EditProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.myprofile.MyProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.searchmovies.SearchMoviesActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.forgotpassword.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <service android:name="com.w3engineers.core.util.VideonFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.w3engineers.core.util.VideonInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.w3engineers.core.util.MyJobService" />

        <!-- The activity below is needed while cropping images -->
        <activity android:name=".ui.aboutus.AboutUsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.privacypolicy.PrivacyPolicyActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.empty.EmptyActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.inputpin.InputPinActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.createnewpassword.CreateNewPasswordActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.welcome.WelcomeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.loadingerror.LoadingErrorActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.downloadmanager.DownloadManagerActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".ui.fullscreenactivity.FullScreeActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    </application>
```

Here below is my module library menifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.project.myapp">
    <!-- PERMISSIONS -->


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name=".utils.MyApp">
        <!-- ACTIVITIES -->

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.TextStatusActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Translucent"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.main.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ShareGroupLinkActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <!--<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>-->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.NewChatActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ChatActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.main.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.FullscreenActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FullScreenTheme" />
        <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.CameraActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ProfilePhotoDialog"
            android:theme="@style/DialogTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ForwardActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">


            <!-- these intent filters to receive data from other apps including images,videos,audio,contacts -->


            <!-- receive text -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- receive one image -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- receive multiple images -->

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- receive one video only -->

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- receive one audio -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- receive contacts -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.UserDetailsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MediaGalleryActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SelectContactNumbersActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ContactDetailsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.settings.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.main.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ProfilePhotoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FullScreenTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.setup.SetupUserActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.NewGroupActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ViewStatusActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MyStatusActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_status"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.main.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.devlomi.fireapp.activities.main.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.CallingActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.NewCallActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.AcceptInviteLink"
            android:theme="@style/DialogTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="@string/group_invite_host"
                    android:pathPrefix="/"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="@string/group_invite_host"
                    android:pathPrefix="/"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.placespicker.PlacesPickerActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" /> <!-- SERVICES -->
        <service
            android:name=".job.NetworkJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service
            android:name=".job.SaveTokenJob"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service
            android:name=".job.SetLastSeenJob"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service
            android:name=".job.SyncContactsJob"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service
            android:name=".services.MyFCMService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".services.FCMRegistrationService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name=".services.InternetConnectedListener"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service android:name=".services.NetworkService" />
        <service
            android:name=".services.AudioService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".receivers.HandleReplyReceiver"
            android:exported="false" />
        <receiver
            android:name=".receivers.MarkAsReadReceiver"
            android:exported="false" />

        <service
            android:name=".services.SyncContactsService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name=".services.CallingService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/maps_api_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/admob_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid"
            android:value="r5oVXgaaSqnhWtqsuMMc" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken"
            android:value="Pv-_XkZ7CsE9EJn5W1Ahcg" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.BackupChatActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_backup_chat"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Below is error that is showing during deployment

```
rg.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:386)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:247)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:159)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
```

How can we resolve this problem?

Comment: Can we see error logs?! :)

Comment: @NickBapu, I have added error log